# Sourcetree Crashes when launched; Win7 & Win10

Tags: windows, crash, atlassian-sourcetree

I've been running Sourcetree and Bitbucket for the past year and a half without any issues. About a month ago, I began running into the below error when launching Sourcetree. Now, it seems, there's no way around it. I've uninstalled and re-installed Source Tree 1.8.3. I've tried to run the 'Repair' from the install wizard, but still no luck.

My firmware developer suggested I need to replace my Windows 7 laptop but I have the same problem on a new Dell Windows 10 laptop.

Anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Rich Blust

> ERROR [2016-07-14 09:10:27,189] [1] [SourceTree.AppRoot] [HandleCrash]
>   - Fatal error System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at
>   SourceTree.AppRoot.OnDeactivated(EventArgs e) in
>   C:\projects\bitbucket.org\atlassian\sourcetreewin-prod\AppRoot.cs:line
>   174    at System.Windows.Application.AppFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam,
>   IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
>   MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate
>   catchHandler)